# Combining probabilities knowing population statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Example: I have a group of fruits divided in apples, peaches and bananas. Every fruit can be yellow, blue or green.

**I want to know the probability that a specific fruit is sweet, knowing its kind and its color.**

Now, I know that these statistics:

- 50% of apples are very_sweet, 33% are sweet, 17% are bitter;
- 33% of bananas are very_sweet, 11% are sweet, 56% are bitter;
- 24% of peaches are very_sweet, 14% are sweet, 62% are bitter;

these:

- 35% of yellow fruits are very_sweet, 15% are sweet, 50% are bitter;
- 20% of green fruits are very_sweet, 20% are sweet, 60% are bitter;
- 80% of blue fruits are very_sweet, 10% are sweet, 10% are bitter;

and these too:

- 20% of fruits are apples, 30% are bananas, 50% are peaches
- 40% of fruits are yellow, 50% are green, 10% are blue

So, **which is the probability that a yellow apple is very_sweet/sweet/bitter? How do I calculate that?**

Note that the sum of very_sweet/sweet/bitter probabilities for a given fruit must be 100%.

Comment: It isn't instantly clear that the answer is determined from the data, though perhaps it is.  To attack the problem, you need to find out the percentage of yellow apples.  To do it, assign percents to each of the $9$ possible fruit (yellow apple, green apple, etc.).  Then write out the equations corresponding to the given information and try to solve them.

Comment: I think your data is not correct. Beacuse the probability to take a very sweet fruit is: $P(very sweet)=p(apple)*p(vs|apple)+\cdots = 0.2*0.55+0.3*0.4+0.5*0.15=0.305$. However we can also compute this via the fruit color: $P(verysweet)=p(yellow)*p(vs|yellow)+\cdots=0.4*0.35+0.5*0.2+0.1*0.8=0.32$. However these two numbers should add up.

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak fixed, thanks, still don't know how to calculate that probability